# Track number of invites for android app

Tags: android, security, hyperlink, invitation

I have a client/server application.
It's an android app backed by php/MySQL server.

I need the user to be able to invite people to download the app
by sharing the download link, something like `http://domain.com/invite.php?userid=12345`
and track the number of people that have clicked on the link (on the server).

I could increment that number every time the link is clicked
but, obviously, the problem is that the user could click on its own link
and increase his/her score.

What is the best way to avoid cheating the invites system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most painless way would be to use cookies to track a re-visit, and possibly validate the User-Agent. It's fairly easy to fake headers though, so it's not the most secure approach.

Alternatively, have a validation page - e.g. the link you share goes to a page requesting either an email address or phone number, then you email or SMS the real link to the new user. This way, you can filter out duplicates fairly easily, at the cost of privacy issues.

There are lots of SMS gateway providers out there, and message costs are fairly low, although you need a paid app for this approach to make sense.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: You're right - the User-Agent can easily be changed and the cookies can be cleared, so these are not the safest approaches...
e-mail validation might just be the best thing to do...

Answer (score 2):

To me, these functionnalities are to be implemented on the server-side. Try to add another tag to your question. For example, you could have the possibility to create a UID for your user, and one for his phone, and then deny every request from his phone when attempting to hit his own link. Just an idea.

Comment: Every user has its uId and deviceId in my database. The problem is that I cannot get deviceId when making a request from (for example) browser application. I could track IP addresses and deny subsequent requests from single IP address but this is not the "perfect" solution because: 1)user can still "invite" himself/herself once; 2)user's IP address can (will) change; 3)user can open the link in his/her computer's browser

Comment: i think you could use a webview within your app to get this done : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html 
 then just post the device Id from the telephony Manager, this could be a solution i guess

Comment: Right, if I understood you correctly, I **could** hit the link from within my app (and send deviceID that way) **but** remember that I'm trying to **invite new users** to download the app - they don't have the app installed yet

Comment: why not suppose the target is in his phone-contacts?
scenario : your registered_user clicks the link within the app, then the server sends the link via mail/sms to the the picked-out-from-phone-targeted-new-user, refering to your app.
[read about the contact api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) i don't see many more options... hope this helps anyway

Comment: I cannot make such assumption because the link is supposed to be shared on facebook :(

Comment: theres a pretty huge API for android though i never worked with it. You could share the link to the contacts using the Facebook account if theres is one (and there OFTEN IS one) synced on the phone. If the user synced his contacts then this is a first step : every single person has his UID on facebook : share the link with them, store their IDs, and filter whenever they were invited ? kind of restrictive on a very permissive network though :s

Comment: Exactly - too restrictive :( Looks like this will not be such a trivial feature to implement and I might need to rethink the whole idea... I appreciate your suggestions anyway, thanks!